# Finding a file with PHP

Tags: php

I want to find a file with a wildcard in the same directory as my index.php is.

When I assign the $file_name manually with the name string, it works fine.

```
<?php
$file_name = glob("*.csv");
$handle = fopen($file_name, "r");
$file = fread($handle, filesize($file_name));
fclose($handle);

echo $file;
?>
```

The browser should output the content of the .csv file, like when I assign the $file_name manually.

Comment: glob() Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a loop because `glob()` returns an array:

```
foreach (glob("*.csv") as $filename) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $file = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    echo $filename;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This script will find some images in working folder.

```
<?php
$workdir = getcwd(); // my working dir
$patternTofind = ".{jpg,gif,png}"; // Images example

$files = glob("$workdir*$patternTofind", GLOB_BRACE); 

// Print result found
print_r($files);
?>
```